# PHP Session recreate (CLI)

Tags: php, session, command-line-interface

I am running a script whitch is ruuning another script in background

```
exec('php index.php test/test/'.Session::instance()->id().' > /dev/null &');
```

As you can see in the example above, I am passing the session ID to it simply because I need to have the same exact session it the script run in background.

Is there a way to recreate session with all its data by knowing the session ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `session_id($theKnownID)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt shm handler in session_*

Or you could implement shared memory in assigned slots, however you would also have to garbage collect these yourself. see http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.shmop.php

As for session, see following, you will either have to choose your own unique ID or let the script print it out first time and then re-use.

Keep in mind, the settings for session.*, in particular lifecycle span, i.e. session.gc_maxlifetime

```
<?php
$cmd=array_shift($argv); // skip 'php script.php' entry
while(count($argv) > 0) {
    $cmd = array_shift($argv);
    if($cmd == "--sid") {
        // SESSID can be anything if we set it manually,
        // default it looks like an md5 like so:
        // b589a6p6s7na1o2ojhff3m1pl7
        $sid = array_shift($argv);
    } else {
        $saveme = $cmd;
    }
}
// must call set session id before starting session
if(isset($sid)) session_id($sid);
session_start();

if(isset($saveme)) $_SESSION['store'] = "iamsaved:".$saveme;
if(isset($_SESSION['store']))
    echo "Session variable :" . $_SESSION['store']."\n";
echo "SID: ".session_id() ."\n";
?>
```

Try this, save as 'script.php', go terminal and enter:

```
php script.php SavedVariable
```

Should output as

```
   ' Session variable :iamsaved:SavedVariable'
   ' SID: sf24r35d98e7smah9abq7ao1i5'
```

Then take the SID and use as parameter for next run:

```
php script.php --sid sf24r35d98e7smah9abq7ao1i5
```

Output will be identical, using the retreived $_SESSION, accessing 'store' value.

Following will also work and let you choose your own SID Note: `PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'`
:

```
php script.php --sid validassockey_as_my_sid AnotherSavedVariable
```

Outputs:

```
   ' Session variable :iamsaved:AnotherSavedVariable'
   ' SID: validsessionid_as_my_sid'
```